# concatenation and double size with c string?

Tags: c

I'm learning C and I need to deal with some c strings.  I'm really shaky with C, especially on the freeing memory stuff, so please inform me if my question is wrong.

I have an empty c string, say size 5, and I want to append a character to it one character at a time. So up to the first 9 characters everything is fine, but once you have more than nine, you need to extend the size of the array to store your character.  So I thought the easiest way of doing this was to use strcat like:

```
char orig[] = "hello";
char temp[1];
temp[0] = ' ';
strcat(orig, temp);
temp[0] = 'w';
strcat(orig, temp);
// etc
```

The string prints out what I expect when I do printf(orig), but I'm worried because I didn't extend the size of orig, since `printf("%d", sizeof(orig))` is still 5, but should be bigger due to adding the temps.  What's the best(simplest) way of solving this problem?

Comment: `sizeof orig` is 6. There is a NUL terminating byte at the last position (`orig[5]`) in the array.

Comment: Also `char temp[1];` can never be a usable string. To be a string it needs a NUL terminating byte, but it only has space for 1 byte so it can only be the empty string.

Comment: I have some code on GitHub that you might be interested in seeing: [`char_vector.h`](https://github.com/dtrebbien/lib_mysqludf_str/blob/master/char_vector.h) and [`char_vector.c`](https://github.com/dtrebbien/lib_mysqludf_str/blob/master/char_vector.c). It simply maintains a dynamic array of `char`s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `orig` is allocated statically, you cannot free and re-allocate it. But you can pre-allocate more space to fit additional characters, like this:

```
char orig[100] = "hello";
```

Note that `sizeof(orig)` would start at 100, and remain at 100, no matter what's the length of the string inside it. To find out the current length of the C string inside it, use `strlen(orig)`.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the size of `orig` explicitly; with a large(ish) value that should be enough for your needs.

```
char orig[1000] = "hello";
```

The bestest way, would be to use pointers and, with the help of `malloc()`, `realloc()`, and `free()` use just enough memory to hold the data. But it's a lot more work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate (and free) memory for the strings.
Also in your code you do not have an empty C string of size 4. Also for strcat you need the destination to have enough space to hold both the strings, whilst you have just allocated a fixed 6 characters (hello plus one for the trailing \0.)

So better to code as

```
char const orig[] = "hello";  // The right hand side is not going to be changed so make the variable const
char * result = malloc( strlen(orig) + 3 );  // 3 is one for each of the letters and one for the trailing \0
strcpy( result, orig ); // copies all of orig and the trailing \0

strcat(result, " ");  
strcat(result, "w");

// extra work

free( result );
```

Comment: String literals, in C, are not `const`. It is Undefined Behaviour to (try to) change them though. Also the data is copied to `orig`; it's a good idea to make pointers point to const chars: `const char *ptr = "readonly";`.